# How to use execute_script in python and selenium to select a value from drop down

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have a form whose elements return elementnotinteractable exception when I use selenium operations like click() and sen_keys.

I used execute_script to interact with elements and it works fine. However, I am unable to perform a select from dropdown operation. I like an execute_script equivalent of following statement -

```
path = ".//div[@id='web_service_dlg']//select[@name='tenancy']/option[@value='Customer Tenancy']"
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(path).click()
```

Above statement fails with the exception elementnotinteractable
I am trying to solve the problem by doing the following -

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='web_service_dlg']//select[@name='tenancy']/option[@value='Customer Tenancy']")
self.browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
self.browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].removeAttribute('onkeypress');", element)
self.browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Above statement does not give me any error, but it is not selecting the element I want. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `selected=true`.

```
self.browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].selected=true;", element)
```